# Creating a channel on guildCreate discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm trying to create a bot that will create a text channel when the bot joins the server. The code I have so far is this but obviously message.guild won't work there. I can't find a work around any help will be appreciated :).

```
client.on("guildCreate", () => {
console.log("Joined server!")

guild.channels.create("text-channel", {type: 'text'})
```

})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [guildCreate](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-guildCreate) Event accepts a parameter which has type `Guild`, you can use it to get a reference to the guild

```js
client.on("guildCreate", guild => { 
  // code
})
```

Comment: Thanks so much :) Would you have any idea how I would send a message after this? I've tried using client.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === "tickets").send("Hello"); but that gives the error can't send property sent of undefined.

Comment: You can access the channels through `guild.channels.cache` but it's out of the scope of this question, would recommend going through the discord.js documentation and looking up the issue and post a new question if you can't find what you're looking for